# What's the backstory of [backstory]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We have a tag [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory). It had less than 15 questions, but I've already removed it from some questions where it didn't make much sense.

But I checked myself before continuing, and thought it better to seek consensus on meta first.

Do we want to keep [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No

1. Does it make sense to be an "expert" in [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory)?
   **No (-1)** — perhaps an expert in the backstory for a specifc franchise or character, but not just backstory in general.
2. Does it make sense for a question to be tagged *only* with [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory)?
   **No (-1)** — there should at least be a tag for the work or franchise in question as well; it's really a meta tag.
3. Does [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory) have a single, universally-unambiguous meaning?
   **Yes (2)**
4. Is [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory) likely to be used correctly just based on its name?
   **Yes (2)**
5. Are there "enough" (> 15) but not "too many" (> 10% site-wide) questions that qualify for [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory)?
   **Maybe (1)** — there were 14 questions before I removed it from some.
6. Are people likely to use [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory) to find questions to answer?
   **No (-1)** — not by itself, *perhaps* in conjunction with another tag, but even that is unlikely.
7. Are there likely some users (*be objective!*) who will favorite or ignore [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory)?
   **No (-1)** — the tag currently exists but has no followers.
8. Could [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory) be reasonably used to feed questions to a specialized chat room?
   **No (-1)**
9. Can [backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstory) be used to search for questions (for any reason) in a way that keyword searching cannot accomplish?
   **Maybe (1)**

Total is **1**, which is low enough to get rid of this tag.

Comment: Pretty sure it's **yes** for #5, since there are some questions qualifying for that tag which never had it (e.g. about Guinan in Star Trek), and also for #9.

Comment: Perhaps **maybe** for #6, if we count searching in conjunction with another tag. E.g. [tag:lord-of-the-rings] + [tag:backstory] = [tag:silmarillion] (more or less), but there are other tags which aren't as lucky as LotR and don't have a special tag for questions about their backstory. E.g. someone who's read a lot about the Star Wars EU might search for SW [tag:backstory] questions to answer, and someone who's just trawled through Theoryland interviews might search for WoT [tag:backstory] questions to answer.

Comment: @randal'thor so your score would be **5** instead of **1**? (#5 1 → 2; #6 -1 → 1; #9 1 → 2). Would that yield a different conclusion?

Comment: Removed the tag from the 5 questions left.

Comment: Not much of a consensus here, but ah well.

Comment: @randal'thor Lack of interest then, perhaps? :)